# How to run a python script from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, json, discord.js

So I'm making a javascript discord bot, if's that's relevant at all.

I made a python script that scrapes one website and return a json object.

How can I make a javascript function that runs the python script, and stores the json object, in order for me to access it's content?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If the python scraping script is not too complex I would consider to implement it in js and by this having a 'cleaner' solution based on js only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider looking at Node.js's [Child Process API](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to spawn and control a Python process. Here's a modified code snippet from the documentation that executes a Python script, collects its output on standard out while it runs, and parses its output as JSON when the script exits.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const script = spawn('python', ['/path/to/script.py']);
const chunks = [];

// there is a data chunk from the script available to read
script.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    chunks.push(data)
});

// no more data left to read, parse our JSON object
script.stdout.on('end', () => {
    let output_buf = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    let object = JSON.parse(output_buf.toString());
    ...
});
```

Comment: I'll look futher into it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! ;)

Comment: I got it to work just like i wanted, thank you very much! ;)